# c++ [] with vector< vector<int> >

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having trouble with accessing elements of the last vector that is contained within a vector.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec1 = {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}}.
```

How to get the second element of the last element of `vec1` ?
I try:

- `vec1.[vec1.end() - 1][1]`
- `vec1.[vec1.at(vec1.end()) - 1][1]`

How can I use at when there are 2 dimensions?

please explain the use of `[]` and `.at()`.

Comment: at() operator checks for vector bounds as vector documentations explains..

Comment: The `begin` and `end` functions returns *iterators* and not indexes. The iterators can not be used as indexes. Not to mention you use the member-access operator `.` to access the overloaded `[]` operator, which is wrong. It seems to me that you could use [a few good books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). From the beginning.

Comment: `at` throws an `out_of_range` exception if the index is out of range. `[]` does not.

Comment: For using at operator with two dimensional vectors you can call vec1.at(2).at(1) for example

Comment: `vec1.size()-1` is what you want. That's an  index to the last vec1 entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `back`, you might simply do:

```
vec1.back()[1];
```

instead of `vec1.[vec1.size() - 1][1]`.

or even the iterator way:

```
(*(vec1.end() - 1))[1]; // or (vec1.end() - 1)->at(1);
```

> please explain the use of `[]` and `.at()`.

`at` does bound checking contrary to `operator []` or `back`.

So for bound checking, use `at` instead of above alternative:

```
vec1.at(vec1.size() - 1).at(1); // std::out_of_range thrown is case of out of bound access.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void test()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec1 = { { 1,2,3 },{ 1,2,3 },{ 1,2,3 },{ 1,2,3 } };
    int last_sec = *(++(--vec1.end())->begin());
}
```

to access the second element of the last element of vec1, you can use --end() to get the last iterator of the vec1, and ++(it->begin()) return the second iterator of it, then dereference to get the element.

[std::vector:operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) return type& without bound checking.
[std::vector::at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) 
Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with bounds checking.